# Extracting pictures/image from asingle cell of an Excel file (xls) using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel, codeigniter-4

I have an excel sheet, I have to extract the image from only one cell with it's name.

I have given en excel sheet in description, as I have extract all the data from excel and saved in database but didn't get first row single image.

[image]

I used this
`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection()` function but it is not extracting single image

The error is showing like ->

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Cell::getDrawingCollection()

Filename: /home/project_name/application/controllers/ProductExcel.php

Line Number: 6662
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Many thanks for the help! :)

Comment: If possible you should use PhpSpreadsheet instead as PHPExcel was deprecated 4 years ago. If not, try doing `$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();`, then calling `$collection = $sheet->getDrawingCollection()`